# Image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform error?

Tags: docker, deployment, dockerfile, containers, devops

This is my docker file

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3:4.4.0
MAINTAINER UNP, https://unp.education
COPY ./flask_api ./deploy
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR ./deploy
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python xgboost.py
```

I am using anaconda prompt for building docker container but I am encounter this error "image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform".
I went through related bugs and found that I have to switch my docker to "windows containers" but still I am getting this error?